# PHP extract unique elements from multidimensional array recursively

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a  multidimensional array with a specific index for each array 
to be more specific, I have a unique ip as the index and entry's as values.

I would like to extract recursively 1 value form each array, never 2 values from the same IP,  and display the bunch as a batch. Never the less I must display the entire set.

To be be a bit more clear, I must extract values from the entire set based on IP uniqueness, each batch must contain 5 values, and I must display each of the values in the list. 
The amount of IP's is never a known value.

for example if I have this array:

```
Array
  (
    [ip] => Array
    (
        [0] => entry01


        [1] => entery02


        [2] => entery03


        [3] => entery04

    )

 [ip] => Array
     (
        [0] => entery05


     )

 [ip] => Array
     (
        [0] => entery06


     )
 )
```

My end resolute should be something like this :

```
  entery01, entery05, entery06
```

Now please notice that we still have values entery02-04 in the first array, that means that once extraction is done i must get them as well.

Answer (score 0):

That associative array isn't possible -- you can only have one `ip` key.

Edit: Assuming `ip` is a placeholder, here's one way to do this: use `in_array()` and add to results array if it doesn't evaluate to `true`.

```
<?php

$begin = array(
    0 => array( 'entry01', 'entry02', 'entry03' ),
    1 => array( 'entry01', 'entry04' ),
    2 => array( 'entry02', 'entry07' )
);

$results = array();
foreach ( $begin as $k1 => $subarr ) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach ( $subarr as $k2 => $entry ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $entry, $results ) && $count < 1 ) {
            $results[] = $entry;
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
var_dump( $results );

?>

$ php unique_items.php 
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "entry01"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "entry04"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "entry02"
}
```

Comment: `ip` is a placeholder for an actual IP address

Comment: regardless the example is a legal array as is, so i updated with a newly keyed example

Answer (score 0):

```
$events = array();
foreach($data_array as $ip=>$evnt_array){
  foreach($evnt_array as $event){
    if(!in_array($event,$events)){
       $events[] = $event
    }
  }
}
```

**Per comment**

```
$events = array();
foreach($data_array as $ip=>$evnt_array){
  foreach($evnt_array as $event){
    if(!in_array($event,$events)){
      $events[] = $event
      break;
    }else{
      continue;
    }
  }
 }
```

In this example, we only take the first element if it is unique and then break out of the interior loop.  If that first element is already indexed, continue on to the next and repeat the check.

Comment: I had this solution too at one point early on, but read "I would like to extract recursively 1 value form each array, never 2 values from the same IP, and display the bunch as a batch. Never the less I must display the entire set." Not incredibly clear I know.

Comment: Just want the first element from each, and only if it is unique?  I can edit it.

Comment: Not my question but yeah, I had to put on an edit to account for this too http://stackoverflow.com/a/11214134/317937

Comment: @DeaconDesperado Beautiful! only problem is that This dose not recursively run over the entire set, granted it get's the job done, partly, but the main issue is getting this to run recursively.

Comment: @DeaconDesperado  OK i think i got this to work only problem is that i cant delete the value ? any ideas ?

Answer (score -1):

I think something like this should work

```
$myInputArray = // your array up there
$myOutputArray = array();
foreach($myInputArray as $ip) {
  foreach($ip as $value) {
    if(!in_array($value,$myOutputArray)){
      $myOutputArray[] = $value;
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, I missed this line:

> I would like to extract recursively 1 value form each array, never 2 values from the same IP, and display the bunch as a batch. Never the less I must display the entire set.

Answer updated

Comment: first off thanks so much for your quick response. 
sadly I tryed that exact peace of code myself and it didn't take, it dose not differentiate between IP's.
And as for your question, nope sorry to say that I can't take duplicates.

Comment: Ok, I added the if statement borrowed from the answer below.  However, what output are you getting when you run code similar to what I gave you?

Comment: I get a none mixed list, with some values missing.

Comment: change the `continue;` to a `break;` and see if that helps

Comment: Nice! but like i mentioned, I'm trying to get this to get all the values, and display them in batches. this one only displays one batch and stop's.

Comment: OK i think i got this to work only problem is that i cant delete the value ? any ideas ?

Comment: Where do you want to delete the value from?

Comment: BTW, I'd love some feedback on why the -1 please.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for a foreach loop. This just grabs the first one.

```
foreach ($arrayName as $ip){
  echo $ip[0];
}
```

I missed some of the question. The above part is no longer a valid response in my mind. I think an associative array with the key being the ip, and the value being the ip would work. Check the array for the key of the ip if it doesn't exist add it if it does exist remove that key from the array. If the length of the array is 5 then you can stop.

Comment: That will just print the first item of each array. The question asks for unique values from a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: First of all thank you all for the great interest in my question, sadly though I ran all these suggestions already with no luck.
The thing is that it must be recursive, AND, it must display a combination of no more the 5 entry's at each iteration.

Comment: You need to clearly point these requirements out in the question.

Comment: I missed some of the question. I think an associative array with the key being the ip, and the value being the ip would work. Check the array for the key of the ip if it doesn't exist add it if it does exist remove that key from the array.